# Visual Studio C++ (Express) 2022, LNK1105 and LNK1104

Tags: linker

I recently started dusting off my C++ skills and fired up a new windows application in VS2022.  What is weird is that the program will compile fine ... until I change something.  When I attempt to compile, it gives me the error LNK1105 "cannot close file ****.exe".  If I attempt to compile again, this time I get LNK1104 "cannot open file ****.exe".  Third time is the charm.  I can still work, but I'm wondering if there is a way around having to compile three times every time I make a change?  I have looked extensively on the web for a solution but nobody's problem seems to quite exactly match this.  Exe is not running in the background; I scanned the task list thoroughly, restarted Visual Studio, even my PC.

Looked in the project directory.  The *.exe is there after the LNK1105 error, but after the LNK1104 error, it disappears.  It reappears after the third and successful compile + link.  All directories are default; even the DirectX directories are included in the default (much easier than it was 20 years ago).

Comment: The error message says the file is open. You can use Microsoft PowerToys (for example) to see which process has the file opened. You've probably opened the app somewhere in the background